# Python Regular Expression Matching

Tags: python, regex

I have a tree represented by strings, for example:

```
A = '1@2@3@'
```

Where 1 is the parent of 2, which is the parent of 3, etc.

I'm trying to get a regular expression which matches only direct children of A.

For instance, if we have:

```
B = '1@2@3@4@' #child of A
C = '1@2@3@4@5@' #not child of A
D = '1@2@3@5@' #child of A
```

What is the regex that, using A, matches B and D, but not C?

Edit: The number of digits between "@" is arbitrary

Comment: Do you mean that you need strings that start with `1@2@3@` followed by a single "node"?

Comment: yes, exactly. Only one node

Comment: *"a tree"*: is this tree always a single chain? Does this format allow a node to have more than one child?

Comment: yes, it will be able to get as many or as few children

Comment: Okay, so the rule is that we want the *full string* to match: the constant string stored in the A variable, followed by a digit, followed by an `@` sign? (Is the "node" always a single numeric digit? What exactly are the rules for it?) What exactly don't you understand about how to write that regex? Are you able to write regexes *at all*? What happens when you try to reason out the regex for this?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. It can be an arbitrary number of digits (1395, 10, etc...)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. I [edit]ed the post to ask the question more directly and [remove noise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721).

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to do this with regex and not string functions?

Comment: yes. I'm new to python I was trying to apply that on pd.str.contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match a string you can write it out directly like this

```
A = '1@2@3@'
str_regex = f"{A}"
```

If you want to match any number at least one you can do this

```
num_regex = "[0-9]+"
```

If you want your regex to match until the end of a string, you need to do like this

```
end_str_regex = "(abc)$"
```

This will force any string that does not end with 'abc' not a match. I believe this would solve your direct children problem. I think your regex would look like this:

```
f"{A}[0-9]+@$"
```

Feel free to modify it if you have further criteria. f-string with regex as above can mess things up so raw f-string or string concatenation can be used. You can read more about regex here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without regex:

```
def ischildof(parent, child):
    return child.startswith(parent) and "@" not in child[len(parent):-1] and child[-1] == "@"
```

Or with regex -- but maybe that's overkill:

```
import re

def ischildof(parent, child):
    return not not re.fullmatch(re.escape(parent) + r"\d+@", child)
```

Example run (for either of the above):

```
A = '1@2@3@'
print(ischildof(A, '1@2@3@4@'))  # True
print(ischildof(A, '1@2@3@4@5@'))  # False
print(ischildof(A, '1@2@3@5@'))  # True
print(ischildof(A, '1@2@3@'))  # False
```